# Jenkins can't use net start <service>?

Tags: jenkins, windows-services, batch-processing

We are trying to stop/start a  windows/java service with Jenkins . The Jenkins server doesn't recognize the `net` batch command. Grasping at straws here, so any workaround is welcome.

Comment: What does "not recognize" mean? Please provide concrete details (exactly what you tried, and exactly what happened) if you wish to receive help!

Comment: I added a run batch command step to my build:
net stop  servicename
and i get:

C:\Users\jenkins\project\workspace\projectDevelopment>net stop servicename
'net' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Ofc net start service and stop works outside of jenkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i found out what was wrong:

For some reason jenkins didnt have my net.exe on the path 
So what worked:

pathtoNet.exe start servicename

Answer (score 0):

If your Jenkins server is hosted on Windows, it should work:
http://www.richardnichols.net/2011/01/use-hudson-now-jenkins-to-restart-a-windows-service/